# Cleaning an Access Team Record in CRM

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, crm

I have to clean/to empty an access team record based on an Access team template.

How can I remove all users in the access team record in one shot? or Getting the list of users and then call `RemoveUserFromRecordTeamRequest()` for each user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
 internal void CleanAccessTeam(IVisibilityService service, Guid recordId)
    {
        QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression(CrmTeam.EntityLogicalName);
        FilterExpression filter = new FilterExpression();
        filter.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression(CrmTeam.Lookups.RegardingObjectId, ConditionOperator.Equal, recordId));
        query.Criteria.AddFilter(filter);
        var teams = service.RetrieveMultipleRecord(query);
        if (teams.Entities.Count > 0)
        {
            service.Delete(CrmTeam.EntityLogicalName, teams.Entities[0].Id);
        }
    }
```